# How to create a list of items where each row is composed of an image, text and a radio button?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, listfield

I'm working with BlackBerry API 7.0 and I'm trying to display a list of countries, each row must display, in the following order, a country flag, the name of the country and a RadioButtonField to indicate the state of selection, something like this:

| -icon- -text- -radio button- |

I've been looking for an example of this kind of control, but haven't found a similar approach.

A RadioButtonGroup only hold RadioButtonFields so, as far as I understand, it isn't what I need.

I know there's the ListField but I haven't found an example of a Manager that implements the look & feel I'm trying to achieve, specially since I have to handle the selection of the RadioButtonField I'm not sure if adding a RadioButtonGroup with a single RadioButtonField to each row is the correct approach (specially since a RadioButtonGroup is not allowed on the Manager class) and if so, how can I handle the state of selection for a radio button on each row?.

What is the best way to implement the design I need? Can this be done with a RadioButtonGroup? Or is it possible to use a custom Manager class for this?

Answer (score -1):

I know that Blackberry has their own API's for various things - and I have absolutely no experience with any of those.

But the standard `List` class offers a way to use images in your list.
You just have to create two arrays first. One with the string-elements and one with the image-elements.

```
String[] theStrings = {"1st item", "2nd item", "3rd item"};
try {
  image1 = Image.createImage("1stimage.png");
  image2 = Image.createImage("2ndimage.png");
  image3 = Image.createImage("3rdimage.png");
} catch (Exception e) {}
Image[] theImages = {image1, image2, image3};
int listType = List.IMPLICIT;
List myList = List("List title", listType, theStrings, theImages);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html

(If this answer is completely wrong in relation to BlackBerry API 7.0, then the "java-me" tag should probably be removed from the question).

Comment: I know, but the design I need must have an image, text and a radio button to indicate selection.

Comment: Hm, I was pretty sure that's exactly what `List` does.

Comment: I downvoted your question because even for J2ME standards you didn't dwell into the specific UI scenario I stated: a list with rows composed of an image and a radio button, your answer only made reference to the image part but you didn't offer any information on radio buttons in a list row, since those components need to reside inside a group I'm left wondering if each row should have an independent group if so how would I handle the selection of each radio button. That is the main issue I'm dealing with right now.

Comment: Use `List.EXCLUSIVE` to get radiobuttons in a list. How about trying out the code before downvoting. ;-) http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/radio-button.shtml

Comment: I added more information on the design I'm trying to achieve. The explicit constant adds the radio button to the left so it doesn't apply to my scenario. I'm using the java-me tag since BlackBerry API uses it, so some things can be translated to it. If you know of a way to customize the default UI design provided by the API that could be translated into BlackBerry API standards then that would be an answer that could help me.

Comment: Also I can't remove the downvote since it is locked unless you edit something on your answer. Edit it if you can provide a bit more of useful information on this topic.

Comment: Well, if you insist on it being that specific, then you need to code your own class. The idea with High Level GUI coding (`Form` stufF), is that it presents itself the way the phone manufactorer decides - and thus presents all apps the same way. If you don't want to use these standards, then you need to code whatever it is you want yourself. No one on SO is going to provide such code for you.